# Need help in accessing image from database

Tags: php, mysql, image

Good day i have a problem with my php and can't find a solution

```
<?php 
$pid = $_REQUEST['pid'];
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT image from images where patient_id='$pid'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs));
{
$imagebytes = $row['images'];
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
echo $imagebytes;
}
?>
```

i call this to another php by

```
echo '<img src="myimage.php?pid=51">';
```

but i keep getting an error 
"Resource interpretted as image but transfferd as MIME type text/html" i been stuck for a while now

Comment: There's a syntax error in your SQL.  I'm guessing `imagefrom` should be `image from`

Comment: I'd advise you to retrieve all of the images and store them on disk space. Store anything other than strings on disk space. Disk space is cheap as compared to DB space.

Comment: Yeah, it is much better to save the URL of the image in the database. Then in your PHP all you need to do is something like `echo "<img src='".$imagebytes."' />";`.

Comment: images is blob type in the DB

Comment: You are wide open to SQL injection attacks! Correct that!

Comment: <img src="myimage.php?pid=51'; drop table images;--">

Comment: found the error just a simple ; was the problem thanks for the answers
will try using disk space instead in storing image

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
if( headers_sent() ) { die('headers already sent by something else'); }
else { header("Content-type: image/jpg"); }

$pid = intval($_REQUEST['pid']);
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT image from images where patient_id=$pid LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    echo $row['image'];
}
exit;
```

It does the most basic of input validation so you don't get SQL injected, checks if something has already sent headers, and removes the inexplicable loop from your code.

Also, the likely reason it was dying is that you have `SELECT image FROM images`, but the field you were trying to access was `$row['images']` which doesn't exist. That was likely printing an error message, causing the default `text/html` headers to be sent before your try to set the `image/jpeg` header.

*Also*, why was `$pid` in quotes in your query? Is it a string? Please tell me you're not storing integers as strings.